Spring Boot with Docker compose support for development - datasource configuration and native builds
I'm developing a Spring Boot 3.3.2 application and I use the docker compose support for development. Starting the application also starts all containers and everything gets auto configured.
Now I want to build a native image so I run ./mvnw -Pnative native:compile and now I get the following error:
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Sure, there is no auto configured datasource.
The question is, how should I set the configuration of the datasource in the application.properties file that on the one hand, the docker compose integration still works and on the other hand, I can build native images and configure the datasource through environment variables. I haven't found anything for that in the spring docs.
I don't know what I should try. The docker compose auto configuration should still work but also native builds should be possible. Best solution would be that I can define all things for services for a native build at the latest possible moment, like when running the native build on the target prod server (MySQL hostname,  user, password). This is the first time I try to build a native image for a Spring Boot service, so any help is really welcome.

The combination of Docker Compose support and AOT / Native does not work currently. You can follow https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/36273 for updates.
